# Вывод всех постов из одной категории

Tags: php, sql

Доброй ночи

Пытаюсь вывести все посты из определённой категории. Выводятся вообще все :)

Контроллер:

```
public function categoryAction()
{
    if (!$this->model->isCategoryExist($this->route['id'])) {
        $this->view->errorCode(404);
    }
    $pagination = new Pagination($this->route, $this->model->pagesCount(), 5);
    $vars = [
        'pagination' => $pagination->get(),
        'count' => $this->model->pagesCount(),
        'list' => $this->model->pagesList($this->route),
        'data' => $this->model->categoryData($this->route['id'])[0],
    ];
    $this->view->render($vars['data']['category'], 0, 0, $vars);
}
```

Модель:

```
public function categoryData($id)
{
    $max = 5;
    $params = [
        'id' => $id,
        'max' => $max,
        'start' => (($route['page'] ?? 1) - 1) * $max,
    ];
    
    // return $this->db->all('SELECT p.*, c.category AS category FROM pages p JOIN categories ON c.id = p.category', $params);
    
    //return $this->db->all('SELECT * FROM `pages`, `categories` ON categories.id = pages.category WHERE categories.id = :id LIMIT :start, :max', $params);

    return $this->db->all('SELECT * FROM pages, categories VALUES (:category) WHERE page.category = categories.id LIMIT :start, :max', $params);

}
```

Счётчик:

```
public function pagesCount()
{
    return $this->db->col('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `pages`');
}
```

Пробовал так:

```
public function pagescategoryCount()
{
    return $this->db->col('SELECT COUNT(category) FROM `pages`');
}
```

но тоже никак.

С запросами мучаюсь уже два дня, ничего не выходит.

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Так у вас в модели запрос по категориям и страницам  - тот который не закомментирован - там вообще нет условия на **id** категории

Comment: Здесь ``'SELECT * FROM pages, categories VALUES (:category) WHERE page.category = categories.id `` нет параметра Id. попробуйте ``'SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page.category = Id``

Comment: ValNik, выдаёт: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 column index out of range in /home/max/www/test/application/li…

Comment: newman, подскажите пожалуйста, как в этом случае сформулировать?

Comment: Чуть поправить запрос SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page**s**.category = Id

Comment: ValNik, вот такой у меня: SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pages.category = id LIMIT :start, :max', $params. Не выходит :(

Comment: Какая ошибка? Проверьте, пожалуйста, подстановку параметра Id в запрос.  SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pages.category = :id LIMIT :start, :max', $params

Comment: ValNik, ну вот такая ошибка: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 column index out of range in /homе…

А как проверить?